# How to use sweetalert2 with express

Tags: node.js, express, sweetalert2

I have been trying to show sweetalerts with following code but nothing is happening when the page loaded.

```
router.get('/', authCheck, (request, response) => {
  let c = swal('this is a title')
  response.render('user/index', {swal: c, user: request.user})
})
```

Is there any way to accomplish such task? I want to show those pop-up messages according to some conditions on back-end after the render process completed.

Comment: would like to see your user/index file, also what exactly is the issue that you're facing?

Comment: It would also be useful to see the html templates being used.